# How do I add a non-standard user-agent to my wurfl file?

Tags: .net, wurfl, 51degrees

TweetMeme's bot uses a custom user-agent (below) that my 51foundation mobile sniffing thinks is a mobile browser.  Does anyone know how to patch the wurfl file to prevent this?

-Thanks

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0b; Windows NT 5.0) Gecko/2009011913 Firefox/3.0.6 TweetmemeBot

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working when using the complete user agent in the patch file.

Place the following before the `</devices>` element in the patch file (web_browsers_patch.xml):

```
<device id="mozilla_ver5"
    user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0b; Windows NT 5.0) Gecko/2009011913 Firefox/3.0.6 TweetmemeBot"
    fall_back="generic_web_browser" />
```

See also my question about [matching partial user-agent strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819042/create-wurfl-patch-matching-partial-user-agent)