# Create WURFL patch matching partial user-agent

Tags: asp.net, mobile-website, user-agent, wurfl, 51degrees

I'm using WURFL to identify whether a user is on a mobile device. Some User-Agent strings are incorrectly recognized as mobile devices which in turn causes the content-type to be set incorrectly.

Here an example of a real life user agent behaving like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (GTmetrix http://gtmetrix.com/; X11; U; Linux i686 (x86_64); en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13
```

The content-type then is set to `application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml` instead of `text/html`.

I would like to add an entry to the web_browsers_patch.xml file in order to recognize it as a non mobile browser.

The following works:

```
<device id="mozilla_ver5"
    user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (GTmetrix http://gtmetrix.com/; X11; U; Linux i686 (x86_64); en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13"
    fall_back="generic_web_browser" />
```

However, in order to no have to add all possible user agent variations, I would like to match it partially. Something like:

```
<device id="mozilla_ver5"
    user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (GTmetrix"
    fall_back="generic_web_browser" />
```

Unfortunately, this does not work - the content type of the page is again set incorrectly.

*Is it possible to add a WURFL patch matching partial user agent strings? How?*

(Related bonus question: How can I determine to which profile a user agent string was matched?)

I'm using the 51Degrees Foundation API available on http://51degrees.codeplex.com/

Comment: wich .NET wurfl API do you use?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention: I'm using Foundation from 51Degrees (FiftyOne.Foundation.dll, 1.0.1.6). I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 51Degrees, you can take apart some of the objects it returns. Take a look here : http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Documentation/Foundation/WURFLMappingTable.aspx

This should get you the user_agent and a bevy of other properties to suit your needs.

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for - I'd like to patch web_browsers_patch.xml to match partial user agent strings.